# Angular component that implements ControlValueAccessor fails for two way binding

Tags: angular, angular-material, custom-controls

A custom component wrapping a material select control and implementing ControlValueAccessor fails to two way bind but successfully binds one way.

**Component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-size-select',
    templateUrl: 'page-size-select.component.html',
    inputs: ['pageSize'],
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: PageSizeSelectComponent,
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class PageSizeSelectComponent  implements ControlValueAccessor{

    pageSizes = [
        { id: 10, name: '10' },
        { id: 25, name: '25' },
        { id: 50, name: '50' },
        { id: -1, name: 'All' }
    ];

    innerPageSize: number;

    constructor() {}

    private changed = new Array<(value: number) => void>();
    private touched = new Array<() => void>();

    get pageSize(): number {
        return this.innerPageSize;
    }

    set pageSize(pageSize: number) {
        if (this.innerPageSize !== pageSize) {
            this.innerPageSize = pageSize;
            this.changed.forEach(f => f(pageSize));
        }
    }

    touch() {
        this.touched.forEach(f => f());
    }

    writeValue(pageSize: number) {
        this.innerPageSize = pageSize;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (value: number) => void) {
        this.changed.push(fn);
    }


    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
        this.touched.push(fn);
    }
}
```

**Component Template**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Page Size..." [(ngModel)]="pageSize" name="pageSize" role="menu">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of pageSizes" [value]="opt.id" role="menuitem">
            {{opt.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Usage succeeds:

```
  <page-size-select [pageSize]="pagination.pageSize" ></page-size-select>
```

Usage fails:

```
  <page-size-select ([pageSize])="pagination.pageSize" ></page-size-select>
```

When the one way binding succeeds it successfully reads the `pagination.pageSize` value into the underlying select control and sets the selected option to that value. The objective however is two way binding but when using that syntax the binding neither reads from nor writes to  `pagination.pageSize`.

Comment: Your registerOnChange makes no sense to me.. Why would you use an array? It should bind `fn` to a callable function within the component which you then call whenever you change the value inside the component. This would make it two-way.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz It's an array of change `fn`. It calls each `fn` whenever the value changes `this.changed.forEach(f => f(pageSize));`. This allows multiple subscriptions to the same event source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a syntax error:

```
([pageSize])="pagination.pageSize"
```

is wrong. Square brackets go on the outside, not round brackets:

```
[(pageSize)]="pagination.pageSize"
```

Also, I'm not sure your `ControlValueAccessor` implementation is correct either. The purpose of the interface is to make the component work with Angular form controls. You are using a `FormControl` without realizing it when you use `ngModel`. So `writeValue` should be calling the registered change function - that is how changes to the component are reflected back to the registered `FormControl` which has to take place in order to write-bind with `ngModel`. You can't have more than one `FormControl`, so you don't need to 'manage multiple subscriptions'. Likewise you need to call your registered touched function - typically when the component is blurred. I've done something very similar to what you are doing, and my `ControlValueAccessor` implementation looks like this (pretty much a cut-and-paste of an Angular example):

```
writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== this._value) {
        this._value = value; // this is my internal value model
        this._onChange(value);
        this.change.emit(this._value); // I fire change events
    }
}

_onChange: (value: any) => void = () => {};
registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
    this._onChange = fn;
}

_onTouched: () => any = () => {};
registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this._onTouched = fn;
}

// if you implement disabled functionality you need this function
setDisabledState(value: boolean): void {
    this._disabled = value; // this is my internal disabled model
}

// and my component's (blur) handler
onBlur() {
    this._onTouched();
    this.blur.emit(this._value); // I fire blur events
}
```

Comment: Syntax error FTW.... not sure why compiler didn't flag that as an unknown property. Silly after hours mistake thx. I also left off `forwardRef` when defining provider - `useExisting: forwardRef(PageSizeSelectComponent)`. and the reason it was supposedly binding one way was not because i had `[pageSize]`="value"` but rather because I had defined `inputs: ['pageSize'],`. So it was binding using a different mechanism.